# How can i delete first spaces each lines in richtextbox(c#)?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i want to delete only first spaces each lines in richtxtbox.i tried to trimstart() command but it's only working for first line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVoXj.png)

Comment: Iterate over your text split up by line break (crlf e.g.) and then you can remove the leading space line by line.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
         str.Split(Environment.NewLine)
            .Select(sub => sub.TrimStart()));
```

Comment: Just what I suggested, but written in a more elegant way. +1.